# How can I save a Canvas to show it again later (rollback effect)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a little problem:

I want to create some kind of time roll back effect.
I have a canvas and my game has different rounds. Now I want to save the canvas every round in an other variable and when the player dies I want to show the canvas of the previous round.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to save the context of the canvas in a variable like a = ctx; and then when I want to show it change it back like ctx = a

Comment: no you can not do the rollback operation in Canvas, but in SVG you can  do it. In canvas, there is no chance to maintain the state of the canvas. So, for that you should be redrawing it...by calling the same logic again whenever you want....

To understand it clearly try read about Canvas vs SVG...ofcourse you please you feel this not related to your question....but it will help you a lot to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

A Canvas element has only 1 unique context throughout its lifetime.  Therefore saving the canvas at any point won't help you because each new drawing after that point will also change your saved context.

You can save the canvas as an image using:

```
var image=new Image();
image.src=context.toDataURL();
```

Then you can later redraw that image back to the canvas with:

```
context.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

Alternatively, you can save all the drawing commands you used to create the canvas and reissue those commands to "return" the canvas to any point in time.